# Display (or get at least) certain cell last modification date in Excel 2003 file (file extension is *.xls)

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, microsoft-excel-2003, cells

I have some Excel table which I filled with values since 2004.
To sad I didn't include each row add date in extra cell. Now I want to know that...
Maybe it still possible? Maybe *.xls file store that dates somehow somewhere?
I read in internet about function `=lastmodified(A1)`, but seems it doesn't present in Excel 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry friend, there is absolutely nothing in Excel that can help with your need. Absolutely nothing.

By the way, imagine a file's size if just 200 cells were used daily for 16 years and maybe changed 3-4-5-6... times a session, and I mean by the user, not modifications recalculation might make. It would not be a feature anyone could really use!

You might consider what "social engineering" kind of approaches you could take. It might be that you can consider the data's meaning, and structure, for clues to when it HAD to have been entered. Maybe just being close on each one's entry point would be good enough. By structure, I mean, say, you kept adding rows. So if you know row 4567 was entered sometime in May 2009, then you know for certain row 10333 was entered some time AFTER May 2009. If you know how fast the data came, as in a day might typically have a single entry, or it might have 4-10 entries, and maybe never on weekends, you could estimate a series of dates between two entries you pin down pretty well:  say you might have seen 4-10 entries a day, but more on the 4 side than the 10 side. You know row 1000 was enter in May 2009 and row 3200 was entered in June 2010. You might then find that's 400-ish days and 2200 entries so 4.5 a day and just use a formula to assign dates with a formula that adds a day to the last date every 4-5, even 3 or 6 now and then, entries, though slightly more slickly than that, so the dates climb smoothly in between the two known dates. If you have backups, even unintentional ones (like you bought a new computer and switched on an exact day, but still own the old computer which you could startup and see what row of data you were on when that day came...), you might be able to place mileposts and then estimate the in-between points like above. Lots of things could occur to you. Even price changes, like gas price information might be in the data or can be inferred and could be useful because you know, or can research a couple huge spikes up or down in its price, or similar things can give you mileposts to interpolate between. Or if it's budget data maybe, seeing particulars like plane tickets, hotel or campground cost entries, can give mileposts. There might be a pattern. Maybe it's video store income records and so Friday-Saturday spikes high, then down Sunday, back up Monday, then in between for Tuesday-Thursday, giving a useful pattern to base dates upon. Lots of other kinds of patterns based on just what the data is. Even if you're a serial killer and it's a record of body parts eaten, it's likely you have outside-of-the-dataset knowledge you can apply.

It's really incredible how interrelated knowledge we participate in can be and how much might not be completely lost to time if considered carefully.

But you will absolutely never know the true dates from anything in Excel so one hopes you don't need exactness.